# Ionic local storage vs secure storage

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic-native, capacitor, ionic5

I am currently using `@ionic-native/secure-storage`, but the problem is that it is not working on android, so I am thinking of using `Plugins.Storage` from `@capacitor/core`.

My question is what are exactly differences between those two. As I know use is not able to see data in both cases, so what makes `@ionic-native/secure-storage` more secure and when is it needed to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@ionic-native/secure-storage` is just an interface to `cordova-plugin-secure-storage`.

The big difference is that `cordova-plugin-secure-storage` uses [encryption for storage on all the platforms it supports](https://github.com/evernym/cordova-plugin-secure-storage#ios).

The `Storage` plugin from Capacitor is meant for simple key-value data, stored in a less secure area on the device.

> On iOS Storage plugin will use UserDefaults and on Android SharedPreferences. Stored data is cleared if the app is uninstalled.